# If I'm on branch-A and I pulled branch-B, is it different if I were on branch-B and I pulled branch-A?

Tags: git

I'm just curious if this is how git works. If `git pull` or `git merge` have a difference depending on what branch I'm on.

So basically, is

```
On branch A: git pull origin B
```

the same as

```
On branch B: git pull origin A
```

Comment: If by "have a difference" you mean that the merge result  (state of  worktree) is different, then the answer is: no. In general, you should get the same worktree for both directions. There may be borderline cases where this is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're different. The first one means

```
git checkout A
git fetch origin B # to FETCH_HEAD
git merge FETCH_HEAD # to branch A
```

while the second is equivalent to

```
git checkout B
git fetch origin A
git merge FETCH_HEAD # to branch B
```

The major difference is which branch is merged to which.

Answer (score 1):

[phd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58114338/1256452) is correct, but I would go further: They can, in some cases, be extremely different.  It really depends on what the names `A` and `B` identify in the Git at the URL over at `origin`.  If these names are *not related* to your names `A` and `B`, the results can be pretty surprising.

As phd said, `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command, typically `git merge`* (but you can choose which command to run second).  The fetch step uses the arguments you gave—in this case, `B` or `A` respectively—to limit what gets fetched.  But: what exactly *does* get fetched?

Remember that Git is really all about *commits*.  You have some set of commits in your repository.  Each of those commits has a unique hash ID.  Their Git, too, has some set of commits in their repository.  Each of their commits has a unique hash ID.  Your Git and their Git—and in fact, every Git in the universe—*agree* on these hash IDs.  So if you and they both have one specific commit, you *both* use the *same* hash ID for that one commit.  That's how your Git and their Git know which commits are which!  Your Git can tell if their commits are new to you, or not, by inspecting the hash IDs.

Where do *branch names* come into this picture?  The answer is: branch names help any Git *find* commits.  A branch name like `A` or `B` tells a Git: *this commit—the hash ID of which is stored under the branch name—is the **last** commit in the branch.*   It's the commits themselves that form the branch.  The *name* just lets Git find the *last* one.  The hash IDs themselves look random.  We (humans) need branch names because there's no way we're going to remember any of the hash IDs, and Git needs them to know where to *start:* at the end of the branch.

But the *names* are *not* shared.  **Their Git has their branch names, and your Git has your branch names, and there's no need for them to match up in any way.**  It's pretty convenient for *you* if you make yours match up with theirs, and Git can help you make that happen—but it's not at all guaranteed.

To help you keep track of this sort of stuff, it's helpful to draw parts of the commit graph.  You can use a graphical viewer (`gitk`, the Git GUI, and many others); some are good and some are not.  Or, you can use the command-line `git log --graph` option.  It's particularly useful with four options combined:

```
git log --all --decorate --graph --oneline
```

which tries to draw a useful summary of all commits on all branches and other references (`--all`), with the interconnecting lines from child commits to their parents (`--graph`) while using a one-line format (`--oneline`) and labeling each commit that has a branch or tag name pointing to it with those branch and/or tag names (`--decorate`).

We can also do this sort of graph-drawing by hand, and that's often pretty useful.  Suppose that you have, in your repository, something that looks like this:

```
...--F--G------H   <-- branch-A
         \
          I--J   <-- branch-B
```

The single uppercase letters here stand in for actual commit hash IDs (which are long and ugly and random-looking); `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` will print actual hash IDs, but abbreviated, and will try to draw this vertically instead:

```
*   b9124f1 (Branch-A) subject line from commit H
| * a123456 (Branch-B) subject line from commit J
| * 02ca132 subject line from commit I
|/
* e310f45 subject line from commit G
* 7720dd4 subject line from commit F
```

for instance.

Now, suppose the name `branch-A` on the *other* Git, the one your Git calls `origin`, identifies the *same* commit as your own `branch-A`.  Suppose further that the other Git's `branch-B` also identifies the same commit as your own `branch-B`.  Then:

```
git fetch origin
```

has your Git call up their Git, find *all* their branches, copy any new commits they have that you don't into your own Git, and then create or update a series of `origin/*` names by taking their names and renaming them.  So after this `git fetch` operation, we can draw *your* Git's contents this way:

```
...--F--G------H   <-- branch-A, origin/branch-A
         \
          I--J   <-- branch-B, origin/branch-B
```

That is, you haven't gained any new *commits* (you both had the same set of commits) but your Git now remembers that *their* `branch-A` identifies commit `H`, just like yours, and *their* `branch-B` identifies commit `J`, just like yours.

But what if that's *not* what their branch names identify?  What if *their* `branch-A` identifies commit `J`, and their `branch-B` identifies commit `F`?  Then you'll have:

```
...--F   <-- origin/branch-B
      \
       G------H   <-- branch-A
        \
         I--J   <-- branch-B, origin/branch-A
```

Or, they might have new commits that you don't.  Maybe their `branch-A` points to a *new* commit whose parent is `H`; let's call that commit `K`:

```
                 K   <-- origin/branch-A
                /
...--F--G------H   <-- branch-A
         \
          I--J   <-- branch-B, origin/branch-B
```

These are all possibilities.  Without actually inspecting your repository after using `git fetch` to get any new commits from their repository and to update your various `origin/*` names, we can't really know what will happen.

But if, in this state of ignorance,<sup>1</sup> we go ahead and run `git pull`, `git pull` will first run `git fetch` and obtain new commits (if there are any) and then run `git merge`.  That `git merge` will try to merge the new commits, if any, or the existing commits, if we already had them, to whatever branch we have checked out right now.  Essentially, we'll ask the other Git: *What commit hash ID does your `branch-A` or `branch-B` identify?*  We'll get any new commits we need, and then we'll `git merge` the commit *their* `branch-A` or `branch-B` identified.  What exactly will that do?  Unless we *know* what *their* `branch-A` or `branch-B` identifies, before we ask them what it identifies, there's no way to know what that will do.

In some (well-controlled) situations, you can be pretty sure what will happen: you know who's allowed to do what to the Git repository over at `origin`, so you can predict, with at least some accuracy anyway, what their `branch-A` or `branch-B` will mean.  In that case, `git pull` isn't all that unsafe.  I still prefer to run `git fetch` separately myself, but you may well be able to use `git pull`.  Just remember that `git pull` means *run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command on whatever fetch brought in*.  If that second command is `git merge`, know what `git merge` does.  If that second command is `git rebase`, know what `git rebase` does.

---

<sup>1</sup>Ignorance here simply means *not knowing*.  It's impossible, in general, to know in advance of the `git fetch` what exactly the `git fetch` will do.  So any time you use `git pull` you're taking chances!  I prefer to run `git fetch` first, then *see what the fetch did*, and only **then** decide whether it's appropriate to run `git merge`.

Comment: "But I would go further" probably *should* be the title of your next book.